# How to plot multiple markers in mplfinance scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, mplfinance

I am using pandas v 1.5.3 and Python 3.10.

I have timeseries data along with flag columns like this:

```
                Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close    Volume    Flag                                              
Date                                                                                                                                          
2018-01-10  155.745697  157.103256  155.353729  156.959854  122.008064   4366109               1                                              
2018-01-12  156.806885  157.495224  155.860428  155.965576  121.235191   5263367               3                                              
2018-01-22  154.407272  156.768646  154.024857  155.449326  120.833931   8870917               1                                              
2018-02-06  143.680695  148.652008  142.552582  148.508606  115.438744  10321614               8                                              
2018-02-09  142.065002  143.919693  138.049713  142.934998  112.200180   8188402               1
```

Here are the data types of the columns in the dataframe.

```
Open              float64                                                                                                                     
High              float64                                                                                                                     
Low               float64                                                                                                                     
Close             float64
Adj Close         float64
Volume              int64
Flag                int64
```

This is the index type:

```
Index dtype
datetime64[ns]
```

I want to use the flag number to determine the type of symbol to plot on the chart (a simple mapping from my boolean flag to a [matplotlib marker symbol](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/markers_api.html) to use on the chart).

This is what I have so far (only relevant part shown):

```
# Define the plot style
ohlc_style = mpf.make_mpf_style(base_mpf_style='charles',
                                y_on_right=False,
                                marketcolors=mpf.make_marketcolors(up='g', down='r'),
                                mavcolors=['purple', 'orange'],
                                figcolor='w')

# Plot the chart with the 'Flag' as scatter points
mpf.plot(df, type='candle', style=ohlc_style, volume=True, show_nontrading=False, addplot=df['Flag'], scatter=True)
```

However, when I run this, it raises the following exception:

```
raise TypeError('kwarg "'+key+'" validator returned False for value: "'+str(value)+'"\n    '+v)
TypeError: kwarg "addplot" validator returned False for value: "Date
2018-01-02    0
2018-01-03    0
2018-01-04    0
2018-01-05    0
2018-01-08    0
             ..
2021-12-27    0
2021-12-28    0
2021-12-29    0
2021-12-30    0
2021-12-31    0
Name: Flag, Length: 1008, dtype: int64"
    'Validator'   : lambda value: isinstance(value,dict) or (isinstance(value,list) and all([isinstance(d,dict) for d in value])) },
```

How do I fix this error, and also to use a mapping function that uses a hardocded map to map from my flag integers to a matplotlib.markers style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Corralien you cannot pass data directly to the `addplot=` kwarg, but rather you must call `mpf.make_addplot()` to generate and "addplot object" to pass as the value of the `addplot=` kwarg.

In addition to this, to have multiple scatter markers, do the following:

When calling `mpf.make_addplot()` set kwarg `marker=` to a list (or tuple) of markers (instead of a single marker value).

[**For some examples, click here**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/scratch_pad/scatter_multiple_markers.ipynb).

Note that if `marker=` is *not* a single marker, then it ***must*** contain the same number of markers that the data frame contains rows.

Note also (as you can [see in the examples](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/scratch_pad/scatter_multiple_markers.ipynb)) kwarg `color=` may also be either a single color, or a list or tuple of colors:  If a list or tuple, then again it must contain the same number of elements as the data frame contains rows.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the examples. What I'm trying to do is this: I have several column flag columns in my dataframe  (for the sake of brevity, I showed only one), so I have Flag1, Flag2 etc. I want to plot each of these Flags (signals, if you will, on a SINGLE candlestick chart). The examples you gave show how to add a SINGLE column. I want to be able to add data from multiple Flag columns (and if possible, show the columns with different markers - to be able to visually differentiate the signals).

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli  ... I assume *you have also read* [**the addplot tutorial**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/addplot.ipynb) which shows that `addplot=` can be set to a ***list* of `mpf.make_addplot()` objects**.  Thus you can pass each Flag (signal) column to a different `mpf.make_addplot()`, each specifying a different marker and color (as is done in the above mentioned tutorial) and pass the entire list into `mpf.plot(df, addplot=...)`

Answer (score 2):

You missed [`mpf.make_addplot`](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/addplot.ipynb):

```
mpf.plot(df, type='candle', style=ohlc_style, volume=True, show_nontrading=False,
         addplot=mpf.make_addplot(df['Flag'], scatter=True))
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks for spotting that. I still need to provide a mapping from the Flag number, to a mtplotlib.marker symbol, so that I can see the different flags, clearly, on the chart. At the moment, they are all using the default `"."` (point) marker.